# Angularjs keeps displaying just 1 records with php

Tags: php, angularjs

Am using the Angularjs script below to submit records to database. it only shows one record which replaces the previous submitted data.

I want it to be displaying each submitted records on its own. I gues the problem might be from the data call

**`$scope.users = response.data;`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body >

        <div ng-app='myapp' ng-controller="userCtrl">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='txt_fname' ng-model='fname'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='txt_lname' ng-model='lname'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='txt_uname' ng-model='uname'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save' ng-click="add()" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="1">

                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>

                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                <td>{{user.fname}}</td>
                <td>{{user.lname}}</td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>

                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

        fetch.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

            // Add new record
            $scope.add = function(){
  var len = 20;

                //var len = $scope.users.length;
                $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'add.php',
                data: {fname:$scope.fname,lname:$scope.lname,uname:$scope.uname,request_type:2,len:len},
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
$scope.users = response.data;
                  //$scope.users.push(response.data[0]);

                });
            }



        }]);

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**add.php**

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$request_type = $data->request_type;


// Insert record
if($request_type == 2){
    $fname = $data->fname;
    $lname = $data->lname;
    $uname = $data->uname;


    mysqli_query($con,"insert into users33(fname,lname,username) values('".$fname."','".$lname."','".$uname."')");
    $lastinsert_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    $return_arr[] = array("id"=>$lastinsert_id,"fname"=>$fname,"lname"=>$lname,"username"=>$uname);
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Comment: Php return only one line. The last one.

Comment: what happened when you used that line: `$scope.users.push(response.data[0]);` ?

Comment: @jeff in my console, it says  Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: @Portekoi, only one record get displayed. That is each time i make an insert, the new form data replaces the previous one instead of displaying on its own on the table

Comment: it's an agular problem then, sorry, cant help

Comment: below the fetch.controller line add $scope.users = []; to initialize a new array of users.  Then use the push as previously mentioned.

Comment: Declare an array and `push` result in it like @Dillon say.

Comment: Dillon you can update the answer so that I can mark it as correct. Thank you so much

Comment: @Markjames11 added answer below, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in comment above, need to initialize an array to push the users into.  See code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body >

        <div ng-app='myapp' ng-controller="userCtrl">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='txt_fname' ng-model='fname'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='txt_lname' ng-model='lname'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='txt_uname' ng-model='uname'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save' ng-click="add()" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table border="1">

                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>

                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                <td>{{user.fname}}</td>
                <td>{{user.lname}}</td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>

                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

        fetch.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            // Initialize user list as array
            $scope.users = [];

            // Add new record
            $scope.add = function(){
                var len = 20;

                //var len = $scope.users.length;
                $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'add.php',
                data: {fname:$scope.fname,lname:$scope.lname,uname:$scope.uname,request_type:2,len:len},
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.users.push(response.data[0]);
                });
            }



        }]);

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```